# Merging module output map

Tags: terraform

I'm trying out the new `for_each` function on a module, which itself outputs some values that I need to pass into another resource.

```
module "vnets" {
    source              = "../caf-virtual-network"
    for_each            = var.vnet_list

    ARM_ENVIRONMENT     = var.ARM_ENVIRONMENT
    ARM_LOCATION        = var.ARM_LOCATION
    ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = var.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    diagnostics_map     = local.diagnostics_map
    location            = var.ARM_LOCATION
    netwatcher          = local.netwatcher
    networking_object   = each.value
    tags                = var.global_settings.tags
    virtual_network_rg  = "${module.names.standard["resource-group"]}-${each.value.vnet.resource_group_name}"
    depends_on          = [
        module.resource_groups_networking
    ]
}
```

I can grab the output of the module for one or more of those objects by specifying something like this
`output "subnets" { value = module.vnets["vnet_shared_services_object"].vnet_subnets }` , which in turn looks like this:

```
"vnet_shared_services_object" = {
    "sn-dev-uks-asdf-app-dynamic" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/asdf/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-shared-services/subnets/sn-dev-uks-asdf-app-dynamic"
    "sn-dev-uks-asdf-artifactory" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/asdf/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-shared-services/subnets/sn-dev-uks-asdf-artifactory"
  }
```

Here I'm specifying the output of ONE object, but I want to dynamically specify the output of both objects in one hit.

**So I want this;**

```
  "vnet_shared_services_object" = {
    "sn-dev-uks-asdf-app-dynamic" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/asdf/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-shared-services/subnets/sn-dev-uks-asdf-app-dynamic"
    "sn-dev-uks-asdf-artifactory" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/asdf/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-shared-services/subnets/sn-dev-uks-asdf-artifactory"
  }
  "vnet_transit_object" = {
    "AzureFirewallSubnet" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/qwer/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-transit/subnets/AzureFirewallSubnet"
    "GatewaySubnet" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/qwer/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-transit/subnets/GatewaySubnet"
    "sn-dev-uks-asdf-bind-dns" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/qwer/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-transit/subnets/sn-dev-uks-asdf-bind-dns"
  }
```

**...output to look like this:**

```
subnets = {
    "sn-dev-uks-asdf-app-dynamic" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/asdf/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-shared-services/subnets/sn-dev-uks-asdf-app-dynamic"
    "sn-dev-uks-asdf-artifactory" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/asdf/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-shared-services/subnets/sn-dev-uks-asdf-artifactory"
    "AzureFirewallSubnet" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/qwer/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-transit/subnets/AzureFirewallSubnet"
    "GatewaySubnet" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/qwer/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-transit/subnets/GatewaySubnet"
    "sn-dev-uks-asdf-bind-dns" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/qwer/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-transit/subnets/sn-dev-uks-asdf-bind-dns"
}
```

So i know doing the following will work, but the point i'm trying to make is that i don't know how many vnet modules i'm going to produce, and thus i need to make this dynamic:

```
output merge{
    value = merge({
        for key, value in module.vnets["vnet_shared_services_object"].vnet_subnets:
            key => value
    },
    {
        for key, value in module.vnets["vnet_transit_object"].vnet_subnets:
            key => value
    })
}
```

Using the guide on Terraform to flatten (https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/flatten.html) the output object works, but it's not how i wish for it to be:

```
output stuff {
    value = flatten([
        for key, value in module.vnets: [
            for subnet, id in value.vnet_subnets: {
                "${subnet}" = id
            }
        ]
    ])
}
```

...which equats to:

```
stuff = [
  {
    "sn-dev-uks-asdf-app-dynamic" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/rg-dev-uks-asdf-vnet-shared-services/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-shared-services/subnets/sn-dev-uks-asdf-app-dynamic"
  },
  {
    "sn-dev-uks-asdf-artifactory" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/rg-dev-uks-asdf-vnet-shared-services/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-shared-services/subnets/sn-dev-uks-asdf-artifactory"
  },
...and so on
]
```

an FYI, this does not help me :(

```
output {
  value = merge(
      for key, value in module.vnets:
        key => value.vnets_subnets
)
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague was able to answer this question with the following code:

```
locals {
    subnet_list = {
        for key, value in module.vnets:
            key => value.vnet_subnets
    }
    subnet_map = merge(values(local.subnet_list)...)
}
```

it is the `...` operator which is the key takeaway from this. you can look it up here; https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#expanding-function-arguments

`...` will expand a list of items to function parameters, hence you can call merge to merge a list of map

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I correctly understand the input maps, but I tried to **replicate** the issue creating some **mock variables**.

For that I created the following variables:

```
variable "vnets" {

  default = { 
  "vnet_shared_services_object" =  {
      "sn-dev-uks-asdf-app-dynamic" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/asdf/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-shared-services/subnets/sn-dev-uks-asdf-app-dynamic"
      "sn-dev-uks-asdf-artifactory" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/asdf/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-shared-services/subnets/sn-dev-uks-asdf-artifactory"
    }

  }

}


variable "vnet_subnets" {

  default = { 
  "vnet_transit_object" = {
      "AzureFirewallSubnet" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/qwer/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-transit/subnets/AzureFirewallSubnet"
      "GatewaySubnet" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/qwer/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-transit/subnets/GatewaySubnet"
      "sn-dev-uks-asdf-bind-dns" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/qwer/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-transit/subnets/sn-dev-uks-asdf-bind-dns"
   }
  
  }

}
```

Then the output was defiend as:

```
output stuff {
    value = {for k,v in flatten([
        for key, value in merge(var.vnets, var.vnet_subnets):
        [for subkey1, subval1 in value: {"${subkey1}" = subval1}]
        
    ]): keys(v)[0] => values(v)[0]}
}
```

which resulted in:

```
stuff = {
  "AzureFirewallSubnet" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/qwer/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-transit/subnets/AzureFirewallSubnet"
  "GatewaySubnet" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/qwer/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-transit/subnets/GatewaySubnet"
  "sn-dev-uks-asdf-app-dynamic" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/asdf/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-shared-services/subnets/sn-dev-uks-asdf-app-dynamic"
  "sn-dev-uks-asdf-artifactory" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/asdf/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-shared-services/subnets/sn-dev-uks-asdf-artifactory"
  "sn-dev-uks-asdf-bind-dns" = "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/qwer/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-dev-uks-asdf-transit/subnets/sn-dev-uks-asdf-bind-dns"
}
```

Comment: cheers, but the problem with this is that you know there are 2 maps you're passing in. where i might have an object with 2, 5, 10 items i wish it iterate over.